# Java 21 suppress compiler "preview feature" warnings - how?

Tags: java

How do I silence the Java 21 compiler from nagging about me using preview features? Here is what I have tried so far, **UNSUCCESSFULLY**:

- In my **Gradle** build file, I added `-Xlint:all`:

```
tasks
        .withType(JavaCompile)
        .configureEach {
            java {
                sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
                targetCompatibility = javaVersion
                options.incremental = true
                options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
                options.compilerArgs += [
                        "--enable-preview",
                        "-Xlint:all",
                        "-Xlint:-preview"
                    ]
            }

        }
```

- Add `@SuppressWarnings("preview")` to all `module-info.java` definitions.

Sampling of compiler warnings (files truncated with ... for brevity):

```
.../DataLoader.java:373: warning: [preview] string templates are a preview feature and may be removed in a future release.
                            logger.log(SEVERE, STR."Error after \{sheet}/\{rowCounter[0]}, \{t}");
                                                   ^
.../DataLoader.java:373: warning: [preview] string templates are a preview feature and may be removed in a future release.
                            logger.log(SEVERE, STR."Error after \{sheet}/\{rowCounter[0]}, \{t}");

warning: [preview] class file .../Named.class) uses preview features of Java SE 21.
warning: [preview] class file for .../ExcelWorkbook$ExcelSheet.class uses preview features of Java SE 21.
warning: [preview] class file for ../Store.class) uses preview features of Java SE 21.
warning: [preview] class file for .../ExcelWorkbook$Field.class uses preview features of Java SE 21.
```

Comment: Can you add some code that triggers the warning you want to suppress?

Comment: @Robert - I updated the question with sample of warnings

Comment: @andrewJames - I use Gradle for building my code + IntelliJ. If you read the question again, you will see that I tried ```-Xlint:-preview```

Comment: I didn't so much want to see the warnings, but the code that triggers them, as a [mcve]. Without the code I cannot try it and change compiler flags and recompile.

Comment: So, what happens if you remove `-Xlint:all` and leave `-Xlint:-preview`?

Comment: @andrewJames this seems to work:
```
options.compilerArgs += [
                        "--enable-preview",
                        "-Xlint:-preview"
                    ]
```

I will mark your suggestion as the correct response

Answer (score 1):

@andrewJames pointed to the solution in the comments:

```
options.compilerArgs += [
 "--enable-preview",
 "-Xlint:-preview"
]
```

Comment: I suspect `"-Xlint:all,-preview"` would also work.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-Xlint-custom.